# Code First Entity Framework 6: 1 to 1 with composite key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I've inherited a legacy SQL database that I am attempting to reverse engineer into Code First. Changing schema is not an option due to legacy software running on current config. What's strange to me is the developer configured the child table to have a composite primary key consisting of a ChildId + ParentId instead of just the ParentId.

Here is what I have:

```
public class Parent
{

    public decimal PkParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    ...
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}


public class Child
{

    public decimal PkChildId { get; set; }
    public decimal PkParentId { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    ...
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And here are my mappings. When I reverse engineered it, EF wanted to create a 1 to many  with a collection of children in the parent, but I really want a 1 to 0 or 1 (a single child may or may not exist, but parent has to).

```
public class ParentConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Parent>
{
    public ParentConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.PkParentId);
        Property(p => p.PkParentId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasOptional(p => p.Child).WithRequired(p => p.Parent);

        // Also tried this
        // HasOptional(p => p.Child).WithRequired(p => p.Parent).Map(p => p.MapKey("PkParentId"));
    }
}

public class ChildConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
{
    public ChildConfiguration()
    {
        // Pk is composite on child
        HasKey(e => new {e.PkChildId, e.PkParentId});
        Property(p => p.PkChildId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}
```

I can fetch parent child together no problem, but if I try to insert a parent and child:

```
        var newParent = new Parent
        {
            ParentName = "XXX",
            Child = new Child { ChildName = "YYY" }
        };
        _dbContext.Parents.Add(newParent);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This results in the following error: The column name 'PkParentId' is specified more than once in the SET clause. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same SET clause. Modify the SET clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If the SET clause updates columns of a view, then the column name 'PkParentId' may appear twice in the view definition.

Sure enough if inspect the generated SQL it is trying to insert PkParentId twice with the Child insert, once as the first parameter and once as the last.It's like EF isn't putting together that PkParentId is the foreign key for the Parent nav property so I tried to add this to the child config:

```
HasRequired(x => x.Parent).WithOptional(y => y.Child).Map(z => z.MapKey("PkParentId"));
```

That yields same error. Oddly I cannot find an Optional relationship that will let me use "HasForeignKey" except WithMany() with forces me back to 1:M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-to-one in EF always encompasses a primary key that is also a foreign key. The child's primary key copies the value(s) of its parent and refers to them by a FK constraint.

But the child's primary key much exactly match the parent's! And it doesn't.

But that's something only you know. EF doesn't have to know that `Child` has a composite key. Just deceive EF a bit by marking `PkChildId` as computed:

```
public ChildConfiguration()
{
    // Pk is composite on child
    HasKey(e => e.PkParentId);
    Property(p => p.PkChildId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
}
```

Now EF will be able to identify `Parent`s and `Child`ren by `PkParentId` only and when a `Child` is inserted it will only read `PkChildId` from the database, but not use it as entity key.

Comment: Thanks, worked great. Can't tell you how many permutations I tried before that.